# Python Colormap for displaying difference in the high value range

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, seaborn

Is there any colormap which displays the differences in high value ranges of an image good, and if not(because I found no cm) is there a way to define it by msyself and give it as argument cmap to seaborn/matplotlib plots? I already tried logarithmic colorscaling but it is hard to define that only the highest 10 percent of your image should be clearly has a nice color difference and the rest could be black for example.
So I have a image/array which has numbers between 0 and 2000. and I only what to clearly differ between numbers between 1800 and 2000.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `imshow`'s `vmin` and `vmax` arguments you can restrict the color range to 1800 to 2000. If you want the lower values to be mapped to black you can use `cmap.set_under(black)`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(-7,7,301)
x,y = np.meshgrid(t,t)
z1 = np.sin(x)*np.cos(6*y) + np.cos(12*x*y)/6
z2 = np.exp(-((x-2)**2+(y-2)**2)*3)
z = (z1*6/7+1)*100+1800-z2*1949

cmap=plt.get_cmap("viridis")
cmap.set_under("black")

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(9,3.0))

im1 = ax1.imshow(z, cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(im1, ax=ax1)

im2 = ax2.imshow(z, vmin=1800, vmax=2000, cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2)


ax1.set_title("Original")
ax2.set_title("Linear between 1800 and 2000")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you want, but you could try to just plot the two groups separately, I mean:

```
vals = np.array([1,2,3,101,120,150])
xs = np.arange(6)
ys = np.arange(6)

mask = vals>100
vals2 = vals[mask]
xs1 = xs[mask]
xs2 = xs[np.logical_not(mask)]
ys1 = ys[mask]
ys2 = ys[np.logical_not(mask)]

plt.scatter(xs2,ys2,c='black')
plt.scatter(xs1,ys1,c=vals2)
plt.show()
```

Of course you can adjust the colormap for second plot so it'll differentiate the 'interesting' points from others